# Adwhirl InMobi multiple ad request

Tags: android, adwhirl

I'm starting to using AdWhirl and trying...

I think something wrong, when application start adwhirl doing multiple adrequest to InMobi after 2 seconds:

```
10-18 01:01:31.798: VERBOSE/InmobiAndroidSDK2.3(32565): requestactivity=AdRequest...
10-18 01:01:32.053: WARN/InmobiAndroidSDK2.3(32565): No Fill. Please try again after sometime.
10-18 01:01:32.058: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565): InMobi failure
10-18 01:01:32.068: INFO/ActivityManager(1992): Displayed activity ...    
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565): Showing ad:
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565):     nid: 1382d...
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565):     name: inmobi
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565):     type: 18
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565):     key: 402ba...
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565):     key2: 
10-18 01:01:32.078: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(32565): Valid adapter, calling handle()
10-18 01:01:32.188: VERBOSE/InmobiAndroidSDK2.3(32565): requestactivity=AdRequest...
10-18 01:01:32.433: WARN/InmobiAndroidSDK2.3(32565): No Fill. Please try again after sometime.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdWhirl goes down the priority backfill order in the same way regardless of what ad network the original request was from.  If inMobi is first in your backfill order, it will try inMobi again after failing to receive an ad from the original inMobi request before going to your second backfill option.